# Drupal 8 block cache

Tags: 8, blocks, caching

I created a simple block where it shows good evening or good afternoon depending on the time.

But the problem is that i have to delete the cache otherwise it will stay at good evening ...

How do i disable the cache for this specific block ?

Here is the twig page:

```
  {% block content %}
{{ content }}
<p>{{ "now"|date("d,n,Y") }}
{% if "now"|date("H") >= '10' %}
 good afternoon,
{% else %}
good evening,
{% endif %}
</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will disable the cache.

```
$build['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
```

[Block Cache API is removed; blocks now use standard caching patterns](https://www.drupal.org/node/2222293)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.

After all i just added my twig code in a views and it worked because i just choose to not cache and it worked.